# Unable to start elasticsearch as service on CENTOS7

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm able to run elasticsearch using the following cmd:

`/opt/elasticsearch-7.15.1/bin/elasticsearch`

but If I would like to configure it as a service I get the following error:

```
   sudo /bin/systemctl enable elasticsearch.service
   [sudo] password for admin:
   Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory
```

Any helps?
I'm using CENTOS-7

Comment: How did you installed elasticsearch? The `elasticsearch.service` is created when you install it using `yum`, but the directory you shared seems to be from a installation made using the `tar.gz` package, so you will not have the `elasticsearch.service` and will need to create it manually.

Comment: @leandrojmp yes you are right. I installed it using tar.
could you please tell me how can I create it manually?